# Public transport in north Morocco

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, morocco

We will visit the north of Morocco in a few weeks and we are planing how to move from a city to another. Specifically, we plan to visit Tanger, Teteuan, Chefchaouen and Asilah

I have been reading different blogs on the internet but I still have some doubts, specially about bus and train lines.

**Bus**:
I know all the cities that I mentioned are connected by bus. But I have read in a (possibly outdated) blog  that it is not possible to buy ticket in advance on the internet. But I discovered https://ctm.ma/ that looks a place to do it. Another blog mentioned that the buses are usually crowded and it is common to have to wait a long time because the first buses fill up.
So:

1. Is this webpage, https://ctm.ma, an oficial or at least a good place to buy tickets?
2. In case answer in 1 is "no", how much truth is there in what I read about the long waits?
3. Do the buses usually  leave on time?

**Train**:
I know all the cities that I mentioned except Chefchaouen are connected by train line (at least indirectly). So:

4. Is this webpage, https://www.oncf.ma, that redirects me to https://www.oncf-voyages.ma, an oficial or at least a good place to buy tickets?
5. Is this really a train? Because I was taking a look for some routes and noticed this:
   (This is from a route from Tanger to Tetouan. And it says "train" at the top, but "autocar" in the bottom)

[image]

6. Do the trains usually  leave on time?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this webpage, https://www.oncf.ma, that redirects me to https://www.oncf-voyages.ma, an oficial or at least a good place to buy tickets?

This is the official page to buy Moroccan train tickets

> Is this really a train? Because I was taking a look for some routes and noticed this: (This is from a route from Tanger to Tetouan. And it says "train" at the top, but "autocar" in the bottom)

*Autocar* means that a bus serves the route, even if it's sold through the train operator.

This is done through ONCF-owned brand of intercity bus service, [Supr@tours](https://www.oncf.ma/fr/Voyageurs/Offres-voyageurs/Transport-rail-route)

---

> But I discovered https://ctm.ma/ that looks a place to do it

This is the website for the main intercity company, of which there are likely **many** others